# All permutation of word in the string java

Tags: java, string

i find the code but i don't understand the recursion part

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the string whose permutations we need to show ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String original=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Results are :");
        permute(original);
    }

    public static   void permute( String input) {
        int inputLength = input.length();
        boolean[ ] used = new boolean[ inputLength ];
        StringBuffer outputString = new StringBuffer();
        char[ ] in = input.toCharArray( );
        doPermute ( in, outputString, used, inputLength, 0 );   
    }

    public static    void doPermute ( char[ ] in, StringBuffer outputString,
    boolean[ ] used, int inputLength, int level)  {
        if( level == inputLength) {
            System.out.println ( outputString.toString());
            return;
        }   
        for( int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++ ) {
            if( used[i] ) continue;
            outputString.append( in[i] );
            used[i] = true;
            doPermute( in,   outputString, used, inputLength, level + 1 );
            used[i] = false;
            outputString.setLength(   outputString.length() - 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

input:

```
ABC
```

OUTPUT:

```
ABC ACB BAC BCA CAB CBA
```

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: `doPermute` is a recursive function.

Comment: i do not understand how doPermute() method work after printing ABC and used[2]=false ,i=2 ,ouputtstring="AB" with for loop increment it should exit from the loop as i=3.

Comment: I do not understand how after ABC rest permution are done with recursive function

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void doPermute(char[] in, StringBuffer outputString,
        boolean[] used, int inputLength, int level) {
    if (level == inputLength) {
        System.out.println(outputString.toString());
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
        if (used[i])
            continue;
        outputString.append(in[i]);
        used[i] = true;
        doPermute(in, outputString, used, inputLength, level + 1);
        used[i] = false;
        outputString.setLength(outputString.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

It take following inputs:

**in**: char array of the input provided

**outputString**: Generated String of each combination

**used**: Has information of the character is used or not in that combination

**inputLength**: the character length to tell the length needed for each combination

**level**: It tells the size of the combination in progress.

e.g.

if you give the input as "ABC"

the call to the doPermute will be as

```
({A,B,C}, "", {false,false,false}, 3, 0)
```

the **used** boolean array is stored in accordance with the  **in** array **i.e. in[0]=A used[0]= false that means "A" is not used**

now it would not go into `if (level == inputLength)` as level is 0 and inputLength is 3

in `for loop` the `outpuString` is appended with "A" and put the **used[0]** as **true**

it call the `doPermute ({A,B,C},"A",{true,false,false},3,1)`

now it will skip the `if` as the length is still 1

enters the `for loop`

skips the **"A"** as the `used[0]` is `true` in next add **"B"** sets the `used[1]` as `true` and calls the function which will add **"C"** and stops.

Comment: OK, you've explained the parameters. Could you also also explain the algorithm itself?

Comment: I changed the answer. hope it will solved the problem